Datasource connection between Excel file and Coldfusion using Cdata driver
I’m currently attempting to establish a data source connection to read an Excel file using ColdFusion. I’ve installed the JDBC Excel driver from CData, but when I try to execute the jar file, I receive an error stating that there is no valid license file, despite having placed the license file in the specified path. Please see the screenshots below for reference.
I’ve placed the license file in the specified path within the ColdFusion library folder, but I’m still encountering the error. My goal is to read data from the Excel file in ColdFusion to generate a sales report. However, to establish the data connection, I need the connection string, which is supposed to be generated after executing the jar file.



Why are you going through all that instead of using cfspreadsheet to read the file's data as a query object? https://cfdocs.org/cfspreadsheet

is the .lic file placed in both the locations shown in the error? That should help get past this.
